# ElasticSearch and Searching in Arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an ES index which has a field which stores its data as an array. In this field, we include the original text, plus text without any punctuation, special characters, etc. The problem is, when searching on the field, the multiple values appears to be skewing the score.

For example, if we search on the term 'up', the document which has the array ['up, up and away', 'up up and away'] is scoring higher with a multi_match (we are using because we may search more than one field) than the document with the array as simply ['up'].

In the end, I guess what I am looking for is a score that emulates calculating a score for each item in the array and returning me the highest. I believe in this case, comparing 'up' to 'Up' and 'Up, Up and Away' will give me a higher score for 'Up'.

With my research, I believe I may need to do custom scoring on this field...? If that is true, am I looking at "score_mode": "max" as what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you slightly over-engineered your index. You don't need to create duplicate fields for the same information and remove punctuation, lowercase fields yourself.

I'd recommend you to read what are elasticsearch token filters and how to create multiple analyzers for the same field.

For your exact use case, if you provided a document sample, it would certainly help. But in any case looking at what you are dealing with - index your array of strings with default analyzer and with a custom one that you'll build yourself. Then you can use the same field, but with different analyzers (differently processed text) to control your score.

Comment: Yeah it does seem like token filters would solve my issue. We are actually stripping more than just punctuation (which it looks like the Standard Analyzer should already be doing anyway..?), but it looks like I might be able to customize the analyzer?

Comment: Yep. I would highly recommend building custom analyzer/analyzers to process text as you wish and then use these different rules to tame scoring. I've done that myself numerous times and it works like a charm.